# Preserving the xticks in multiple bar plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

1) I am not able to see the text-based xticks which are stored as list in the variable x. When I have only one single column based bar plot, I can see the xticks as text but not for more.

2)how can I control the font properties of xticks and the values in y axis?

Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

#load text and columns into different variables
data = np.genfromtxt('a', names=True, dtype=None, usecols=("X", "N2", "J2", "V2", "asd", "xyz"))  
x = data['X'] 
n = data['N2'] 
j = data['J2'] 
v = data['V2'] 

#make x axis string based labels
r=np.arange(1,25,1.5)
plt.xticks(r,x)             #make sure dimension of x and n matches

plt.figure(figsize=(3.2,2), dpi=300, linewidth=3.0)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(r,v,width=0.9,color='red',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')
plt.axhline(y=0,linewidth=1.0,color='black')   #horizontal line at y=0
plt.axis([0.5,16.5,-0.4,0.20])

ax.bar(r,j,width=0.6,color='green',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')
ax.bar(r,n,width=0.3,color='blue',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')

plt.axhline(y=0,linewidth=1,color='black')   #horizontal line at y=0

plt.axis([0.5,24.5,-0.36,0.15])

plt.savefig('fig',dpi=300,format='png',orientation='landscape')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're doing it, you just need to move the call to `plt.xticks(r,x)` to somewhere *after* you create the figure you're working on. Otherwise `pyplot` will create a new figure for you.

However, I would also consider switching to the more explicit [object-oriented interface](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pythonic_matplotlib.html) to `matplotlib`.

This way you'd use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) # your only call to plt

ax.bar(r,v,width=0.9,color='red',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')
ax.bar(r,j,width=0.6,color='green',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')
ax.bar(r,n,width=0.3,color='blue',edgecolor='black', lw=0.5, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(r)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.axhline(y=0,linewidth=1,color='black')

fig.savefig('fig',dpi=300,format='png',orientation='landscape')
# or use plt.show() to see the figure interactively or inline, depending on backend
# (see Joe Kington's comment below)
```

Comment: Minor side note: `fig.show()` won't actually show the figure with some common backends (it shows the window, but doesn't enter the gui mainloop). `ipython` will run the gui's mainloop in a separate thread, so `fig.show()` is a good way to show the figure while allowing further work.  However, the same thing in a "bare" python script will show the figure and immediately exit. However, `plt.show()` should always work.  Might be better to recommend `plt.show()` in the comment.

Comment: Could you please explain what "fig, ax" in the first line means and how it differs from the plt.figure(...) line I have in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @JoeKington. I'm pretty much always using `ipython` or a notebook with the inline backend, so this is good to know.

Comment: @user274642 `plt.subplots` will create a `figure` and an `axes` object (or multiple `axes` objects) for you. It just returns them as a tuple, which I am expanding into `fig` and `ax` separately for clarity. This is handy because it allows you to keep references to the specific `figure` and `axes` you want to work on. Most of the functions you want to call will then be part of the `axes` api.

Comment: I thought I was clear but I don't think so. Can I really have a comma within the subplot(): It throws a value error for me saying illegal argument? If I have 111 within subplot, I get "TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable". The whole point being, how do I incorporate the figsize and dpi arguments to the "fig, ax" line?

Comment: Sorry, `plt.subplot` and `plt.subplots` are different commands. I just prefer `subplots` because I find the arguments more clear. If you're using the code I provided, make sure you're using `plt.subplots`. If you have other questions (e.g. how to change the size of a figure) you should probably post them separately.